# Let $( X,\tau)$ be a countable Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology

Let $( X,\tau)$ be a countable Hausdorff space.

> Is there a topology $ \sigma \subset \tau$ s.t $( X, \sigma)$ is a second
>   countable Hausdorff space?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $X=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$. Let $P=\{\langle m,n\rangle\in\omega\times\omega:m<n\}$; $P$ is countable. For each $\langle m,n\rangle\in P$ there are $U(m,n),V(m,n)\in\tau$ such that $x_m\in U(m,n)$, $x_n\in V(m,n)$, and $U(m,n)\cap V(m,n)=\varnothing$. Let $$\mathscr{S}=\{U(m,n):\langle m,n\rangle\in P\}\cup\{V(m,n):\langle m,n\rangle\in P\}\;;$$ $\mathscr{S}\subseteq\tau$, and $\mathscr{S}$ is countable. Let $\sigma$ be the topology on $X$ generated by the subbase $\mathscr{S}$; the family $$\mathscr{B}=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathscr{S}\text{ is finite}\right\}$$ is a base for $\sigma$, and clearly $\mathscr{B}$ is countable, so $\langle X,\sigma\rangle$ is second countable. Finally, if $x$ and $y$ are distinct points of $X$, then $\{x,y\}=\{x_m,x_n\}$ for some $\langle m,n\rangle\in P$, so $U(m,n)$ and $V(m,n)$ are disjoint $\sigma$-open sets separating $x$ and $y$, and $\langle X,\sigma\rangle$ is Hausdorff.